# iOS pattern for editable vs read-only fields

Tags: forms, mobile, ios

I am working on an iOS app for hotels, allowing users to take reservations, check in/out, assign rooms, etc.

**Main Issue:** In the included mock up, there is no indication for when a field is editable vs read-only. I'm concerned users will experience tap fatigue when trying to figure out what they can and cannot edit.

---

- The **Status**, **Arrival**, **Departure**, **Room**, and **Guest Notes** fields are editable and reveal pickers/text inputs when tapped
- **Reservation Total**, **Reservation ID** and **Received** are read-only

The **Guests** section is mixed:

- **Fred Jensen** slides in a new screen with more info when tapped, which is then editable (address, phone, etc.)
- **Jimmy Jensen** is read-only (b/c he's not the primary reservation holder)

---

One solution is to have an **Edit** button in the global nav bar. Like the native iOS Contacts app, it would only show the editable fields. The downside is that it adds 1 more tap to the workflow; tapping Edit and then tapping on the desired field.

Is there an established convention for this issue iOS design? Any suggestions?

[image: mockup]

Comment: FYI, Jimmy is not a woman's name.

Comment: @plainclothes Why do you expect to see a woman's name? Jimmy is even referenced as a man ("he's not the...") in the prose description.

Comment: @msanford because in the wireframe "Jimmy"  has the female icon next to his name.

Comment: Interesting that you interpreted the icon as meaning female. It is actually supposed to mean child. I probably need to revisit that icon.

Answer (score 2):

The convention on iOS seems to be that if a field is editable, it'll have a disclosure arrow ( > ), and tapping that field slides in a new view where you can enter a new value or select from a list of options (for example, see Settings > General > About).

You've already used a disclosure arrow in the Guests section, so I'd suggest just being consistent and carrying that through to the other editable fields: Status, Arrival, Departure, etc. That way, the user can tell which fields are editable and which aren't at a glance, and you avoid the need for a separate Edit mode, which is clumsy.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My only difficulty with that is that I need a UI pattern to indicate when tapping on a field will reveal further information (i.e. the arrow next to Fred Jensen reveals his contact info) vs when tapping on a field will allow the user to edit the field.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: The disclosure arrow (>) is good for fields that bring up contextual menus (Date picker), but for plain text, I'd avoid using the arrow.

Answer (score 1):

I would make data in non-editable fields a medium gray. You want to visually differentiate the editable fields from the editable data (which should stay black).

Alternately you could inset a small edit-icon (diagonal pencil) after the field title or next to the editable data.